# kubernetes - expose content from nginx docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a docker nginx container image `nha/my-nginx-img`.
And I have a one-node kubernetes cluster, installed on bare metal. I am trying to deploy and expose this nginx container (which works fine locally otherwise).

I ran `kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml` on this file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-nginx
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nha/my-nginx-img
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
#
# Expose Service
#
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
spec:
  # I thought using NodePort here 
  # would expose the port on the node?
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    run: my-nginx
```

I can see them running:

```
kubectl get pods -l run=my-nginx -o wide
NAME                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP               NODE
my-nginx-5ccbf78584-4lxsn   1/1       Running   0          1d        10.233.102.181   node1
my-nginx-5ccbf78584-6qkml   1/1       Running   0          1d        10.233.102.182   node1
```

However:
- the IPs show in the resulting command above are NOT the IP of my machine
- when I curl the IP of my machine, I do not get a reply on either the port 80 or 443

**How do I get this static content to be served by nginx?**

***Additional information***

`kubectl get services` gives:

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.233.0.1     <none>        443/TCP                      2d
my-nginx     NodePort    10.233.16.91   <none>        80:31081/TCP,443:31856/TCP   5h
```

(10.233.16.91 is NOT my IP)

And `kubectl describe service my-nginx`:

```
Name:                     my-nginx
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=my-nginx
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"run":"my-nginx"},"name":"my-nginx","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[...
Selector:                 run=my-nginx
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.233.16.91
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31081/TCP
Endpoints:                10.233.102.181:80,10.233.102.182:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31856/TCP
Endpoints:                10.233.102.181:443,10.233.102.182:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Again, I do not see my IP anywhere in there.

Also, I created the cluster using [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want the service, not the pod. The pod is not exposed to anything except the local kubernetes network, this is why you create the service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
spec:
  # I thought using NodePort here 
  # would expose the port on the node?
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    run: my-nginx
```

This here defines the service, and it does expose the port on the node, but the IP you see is the internal "cluster IP" which can only be accessed by other pods.

So you might try `kubectl get services`

[image]

This will show you the external ip of the port that is exposed.

Also check out `kubectl describe service yourServiceName`

Comment: Thanks! I don't completely get "You'll want the service, not the pod." - I miss a part in my `yaml` definition? Also I ran the commands and I cannot see my machine's IP in there. I actually do not know where these IPs come from.

Comment: @nha No, you didn't miss a part in your YAML definition, I think you just don't understand it. Your pod is never exposed so you will never see the node IP if you look up kubectl describe pods. The service is what exposes the pod so you must look up the service. You should try kubectl describe service yourServiceName, I cannot check right now but I believe the correct ip is in there next to a marker that says "nodePort"

Comment: Yes I am very new to kubernetes. I edited my question to include the results of the commands you pointed out. The node port is there indeed, but not the value I expected. And you are correct, there is no "EXTERNAL-IP" for my-nginx.

Comment: @nha The NodePort shows the port your service is exposed on, which is 31081, so if you curl your machines IP on that port, then you will get the response. If you want to manually specify a nodeport you must do that in your YAML definition of the service.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get this static content to be served by nginx?

You created service of [`NodePort` type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport). Use `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`. In your example, `http://<NodeIP>:31081`, `https://<NodeIP>:31856`. Also `<ClusterIP>:<Port>` works inside the cluster.

Strongly recommended docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: I was going to comment on @RubyJunk answer - it looks like I should be able to reach it indeed, however I do not get any reply. Any advice on how to debug that?

Comment: @nha "however I do not get any reply", what's the exact response when you curl `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`? I've used the yaml you provided (only with different image:`nginx:1.7.9`) and it works. And no network issue (firewall, etc.)?

Comment: No network issue that I know of (I can  ssh into the box, start a simple python server on port 8081 and see it in the browser).
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 12.34.56.78 port 31081: Connection refused`. I can run my image locally too `docker run -p 10001:80 nha/my-nginx-img` locally -> localhost:10001 will return a static page.

Comment: It turns out my images was misconfigured - thanks a lot for the help!